# Return row from object array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object array that contains states. It has three fields (id, name, abbr)

To simplify things, I'll use three states:

```
states: any = [{
      "stateId": 3,
      "stateName": "Arizona",
      "stateAbbreviation": "AZ"
    },
    {
      "stateId": 4,
      "stateName": "Arkansas",
      "stateAbbreviation": "AR"
    },
    {
      "stateId": 5,
      "stateName": "California",
      "stateAbbreviation": "CA"
    }]
```

I have a provider where I want to return an object if it matches the stateId I pass it.

So in my provider I have the following funciton:

```
  getState(stateId){
    this.states.forEach(function(element) {
      if(element.stateId == stateId){
        return element;
      }  
    });
  }
```

In my home controller I simply call it like this:

```
console.log('State is: ', this.states.getState(50));
```

But I'm getting the error: undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to return the result of. So add a return statement. Also use the `fitler` operator instead `forEach`

```
getState(stateId){
    return this.states.filter(function(element) {
      if(element.stateId == stateId){
        return element;
      }  
    });
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdtb1y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Sachila, that didn't work. I still get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use the `filter` function:

```
getState(stateId){
  return this.states.filter(function(element) {
    return element.stateId == stateId);
  });
}
```

Note the first `return` statement used to return the result of the `filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem because `forEach` not return everything.

In `typescript` you can try this one.

```
getState(stateId) {
    return this.states.find(x => x.stateId == stateId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **[From Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**
>   `forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array
>   element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` it always returns the value
>   undefined and is not chainable

You need [`filter() method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
**Modified Code**

```
 getState(stateId){


      return this.states.filter(element=> {
          if(element.stateId == stateId){
            return element;
          }  
        });
      }
```

[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6extqn);

Or you could use [find() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
getState(stateId){
    return this.states.find(element=> {
      if(element.stateId == stateId){
        return element;
      }  
    });
```

[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvf5py)

*`filter()` runs till the end of the array, and invokes its callback on every item; in contrast to `find()` which stops after having found one.*